# Remove a row in 3d array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

given the index of a row, l would like to remove that row.

l tried the following :

```
a.shape
Out[128]: (60, 3)
```

when l try to remove the row number 14 from my 3D array **a** as follow :

```
np.delete(a,14,axis=0)
a.shape
Out[130]: (60, 3)
```

l noticed that it doesn't make any chage. l supposed to get  : 
    a.shape
    Out[130]: (59, 3) # rather than (60,3)

What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment will solve it as apparently [delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) returns an array instead of working inplace:

```
a = np.delete(a,14,axis=0)
```

Comment: Yes it does. I'm wondering why delete doesn't work in working place ?

Comment: It's the implementation. Oftentimes assignment is better then inplace, saves you lot of trouble.

Comment: it's strange because numpy.append() works without assignments

Comment: I get that it is because when you append you want to do it inplace for sure and when deleting it is best that you save it to a copy.

Comment: Let me share with you a strange thing that l just discover with np.append. l have an array  b.shape=(118,)  l added to it an element as follow np.append(b,a)  . The element a appear in b definitely but when l make b.shape it remains the same b.shape=(118,) rather than (119,) !!

Comment: Sorry [append](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) doesn't work inplace as well.